# GroupBy, then order another list based on group in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have one `List` of objects that looks somthing like this

```
class Item
{
    int ItemId;
    string Name;
    DateTime CreatedDate;
    ... more properties, but not relevant ...
}
```

and another that holds votes

```
class Vote
{
    int ItemId;
    ... more properties, but not relevant ...
}
```

So the vote points to an item. I've gathered all the votes from the database, and stored them in a List

```
var votes = GetAllVotes().ToLookup(v => v.ItemId).OrderByDescending(v => v.Count());
```

Now I have a list that gives me the itemId's with the most votes in a good list. Is there a way for me to sort my list of items based on the votes list?

```
var items = GetAllItems().OrderBy(i => i.CreatedDate);
//then I want to do something like this:
items.OrderBy(votes.Select(v => v.Key, v.Count())
```

So the goal here is that the items gets sorted by number of votes, and all the items with 0 votes keep their sorting by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
from item in GetAllItems()
join vote in GetAllVotes() on item.ItemId equals vote.VoteId into votes
orderby votes.Count() descending, item.CreatedDate
select new { Item = item, Votes = votes.Count() };
```

(I can put that in non-query-expression notation if you want, but it won't be as neat.)

Comment: Yes. That exactly what I wanted, but I you already knew that, didn't you? You probably had the answer written out on Notepad a couple of minutes before I even asked the question.